# Inheritance in entities, using objectbox

Tags: java, android, inheritance, objectbox

In my code I put some base fields in base abstract class `BaseEntity`:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    public BaseEntity() {
    }

    public BaseEntity(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

So, in child class `User` I am not define an `id` field:

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
    private String login;
    private String gender;

    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

    private Date registrationDate;
    private Date lastActivityDate;

    private long systemId;

    public User() {
    }

...Getters and Setters
}
```

because it defined in superclass. I don't want to create in every class an `id` field, and don't want to persist in database `BaseEntity` class. And I get an error:
`Error:[ObjectBox] Code generation failed: No ID property found for Entity User (package:...)`

How can I use objectbox with an inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism of entities is not supported at this time, but there is a [feature request](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/5).

If it helps, you can go for an interface. E.g.:

```
public interface BaseEntity {
    long getId();
}
```

Note: you could have a setter for the ID, but my personal advice would be to have the id field package private (so ObjectBox has access from generated classes) and not have a setter because it would suggest it's OK to change the ID at any time.

**Update:** ObjectBox 1.4 introduced [entity inheritance](http://objectbox.io/documentation/entity-inheritance/) (non-polymorphic).

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg Objectbox don't support inheritance in entity class as it will map every entity to a separate table in db and use this @Id variable as unique id to identify a row(entity instance) in that table. Thus @Id variable is must for every entity class.

In general,

for each for Child class to access Parent class variables it have to be either protected or public but in your id is private so change it to either protected it will work.

```
    protected long id;
```

if you mark it is as protected only the parent and its child class can access it and when you mark it as public any class can access it.
marking it as private means only parent class can access it

Comment: yes, you are right . Objectbox sees every entity as a table in db.Thus it will convert every entity into a table in db and to do that it needs a id column to identify every row in that table thus it requires @Id variable in every entity.

Comment: While using Objectbox you must first design your DataBase and tables it must have then create one entitiy for every table . By that way you won't get any confusion like this.